# Vertical align input and button without bootstrap

Tags: html, css, web-deployment

I wonder what's the best way to vertically align an input field and a button **without** Bootstrap.

Here's how it looks right know:

[image]

Some code:

```
<!doctype html>
        <title>Postnummer</title>
      <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="divider"></div>
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-12">
                  <form class="navbar-form">
                    <div class="input-group">
                      <input style="height:50px; color: black; border-radius: 0px;" type="number"  id="searchZipCode"class="form-control" placeholder="Sök postnummer">
                      <div class="input-group-btn">
                      <a id="submitBtn">
                        <button style="height:50px; border-radius: 0px" type="button" click="submitZipCode()" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-search fa-2x"></i></button>
                      </a>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </form>
              </div>
          </div>
    </div>
```

**Fiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/5mxzu4m5/

I want the the icon on the right side of the input field. Really grateful for all the answers! :)

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle or code snippet

Comment: Yes. I have updated my question.

Comment: show what you have tried so far in code

Comment: Share your codes.

Comment: I have now updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below code (just added display:inline-block & vertical-align:top on textbox and .input-group-btn, increased button height)

```
<div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="divider"></div>
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
              <form class="navbar-form">
                <div class="input-group" style="text-align: center">
                  <input style="height:50px; color: black; border-radius: 0px; display: inline-block; vertical-align:top; margin-right:-4px; " type="number"  id="searchZipCode"class="form-control" placeholder="Sök postnummer">
                  <div class="input-group-btn" style="display: inline-block; vertical-align:top">
                  <a id="submitBtn">
                    <button style="height:56px; border-radius: 0px;" type="button" click="submitZipCode()" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-search fa-2x"></i></button>
                  </a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </form>
          </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How should I do if I want them in the center of the screen? Thanks for the reply btw!

Comment: Better remove the inline styles and add them into css class

Answer (score 0):

Simple and Sleek Solution:
Replace src="..." with your link

**HTML**

```
<div>
<input type="text" id="text1">
<br>
<img src="http://findicons.com/files/icons/1264/clearblack/128/find.png" height="50px" width="50px">
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
img{
  float:right;
}
div{
  width:90px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this CSS

```
.input-group{
  display:table;
}
.form-control,.input-group-btn
{
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

[Link For Reference](https://jsfiddle.net/DChandraShekhar/5j0t3t7h/1/)

style your button accordingly

hope this helps..